# Pyinstaller's 'onedir' mode creates too many files

Tags: python, pyinstaller, software-distribution

I am "compiling" my Python application for Windows with PyInstaller 2.1. I initially tried using `onefile` mode, but [onefile takes a long time to startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474575/3357935) (decompressing `wx` and `matplotlib`). With the `onedir` mode it's pretty fast (only a little bit slower than native python).

So I want to use `onedir` mode for faster startup times, but for the end-user it's difficult to find the actual `*.exe` file inside the huge amount of files located in the main directory (there are 98 files including the actual executable and it's manifest).

I want to make sure a non tech-savvy user can easily "double-click" the executable and work with this program (ease and portability) without a long disclaimer to "just ignore" the 97 other files there.

Is it possible to move all those "distracting" files into a subfolder? Or are there other ways to make it easy for the end-user to run this program?

Comment: Related Article: [*PyInstaller – Separating the executable from the ‘onedir’*](http://unafaltadecomprension.blogspot.com/2014/07/pyinstaller-separating-executable-from.html), Issue on GitHub: [*Onedir with exe outside the dir*](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1048)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could use onedir. The resulting folder you can put anywhere and create a shortcut to the user where it is more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to reduce the number of files created in `--onedir` mode would be to create a virtual environment and install only the necessary modules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use some software to pack it into a one-file installer, such as `Inno setup`.
You could also try to delete some files one by one (if the executable fails just undelete it). I figured out that almost half of the files can be deleted with the executable working fine.

Download `Inno Setup` from [here](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).