# Convert pygame and tkinter to exe

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I have made a program which uses pygame, tkinter, pyttsx3 and more. I want to convert this program to and executable .exe file to share with my friends. How can I do that without any issues?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a .py to .exe for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting tkinter to exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299396/converting-tkinter-to-exe)

Answer (score 0):

To convert your pythone code into an executable file I suggest to use the tool pyinstaller.
in your command prompt:

```
> pip install pyinstaller
```

Then in cmd open the current folder where you have the code stored. For example

```
> D:
> cd folder
```

Then you just run the command (with the name of your file where you have the code):

```
> pyinstaller --onefile code.py
```

You will find your executable in a separate folder called dist

I hope it helps you, it should work. It is how I transformed my codes into executable.

Comment: No! After doing this just some python screen opens and nothing happen.

Comment: Do you have all your code in one file ? Or you use multiple files with different code for this application

Comment: All the codes are in one file. When i open the exe only a black screen open but the pygame window doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is py2exe.

```
pip install py2exe
```

Or on Linux:

```
pip3 install py2exe
```

Here's the link to the tutorial on the py2exe website.
https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial