# Run Selenium Projects on another PC | Python

Tags: python, selenium

I was working on a selenium project that works with google drive api and google sheets but I needed to run my project as a .exe file so I converted it with pyinstaller and it worked well but when I tried to move it to another PC, with a different gmail account, and entered a new google sheet name and worksheet name, it didn't recognize them, but recognized the old files from the past email, how come? In other words, which account will selenium see, the default or the current?

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


def sheet_access(sheet_name, worksheet_name):
    scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet = client.open(sheet_name).worksheet(worksheet_name)
    return sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

To have it run in any computer you can use Docker but if you want an .exe file you can use Tkinter and create a GUI as well.

[Tkinter site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

[Converting Tkinter to exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299396/converting-tkinter-to-exe)

Comment: sorry, maybe I didn't made it clear I can't access the drive of the current gmail but the gmail of the old account, doesn't selenium see the current account?

Comment: The setup should be universal, not just using your email credential but give the user to add them

Comment: selenium should see the current used gmail

Comment: Then you should update and show your code

Comment: it should access this drive not the one used while programming

Comment: Then change the setup and put your new google apps credentials. Go to the google console and generate the API keys that the program is asking for and put them into the `client_secret.json` file