# How can improve the performance of my python standalone app?

Tags: python, executable, python-standalone

I have compiled a python application using pyinstaller. The thing is that I want to execute it on a computer without python installed and I want it to be only one exe file without dependencies.

I have tried both "onefile" and "onedir" compilations to build an exe for windows, but "onefile" takes some time to execute because it has to decompress all the packages and I don't like "onedir" because it creates dependencies.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App created with PyInstaller has a slow startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469932/app-created-with-pyinstaller-has-a-slow-startup)

Comment: I know what is happening, but what I'm asking for is another way to do create one exe file without directorioes.