# auto-py-to-exe layout issues mac

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, customtkinter, auto-py-to-exe

I wrote a tkinter/customtkinter based Python app, which I am exporting to an executable on Windows and macOS alike.

On macOS, I am currently facing the issue, that auto-py-to-exe opens but once I press the "browse" button to import my main.py it immediately opens a blank tk window accompanied by the rainbow spinner and has a lot of trouble opening the system dialog for importing/setting paths.
The system dialog seems to get stuck outside of the display "zone".
When I try to reposition the system dialog window, it stays stuck, I basically can't move it, I can only change its position a little bit by resizing it, but it stays stuck halfway outside of the view.

I can set paths for my app using auto-py-to-exe, by blindly navigating the system dialogs using my keyboard but not using my mouse.

My setup:
macOS: Ventura 13.1
Python: 3.11.5
pip: 23.2.1
auto-py-to-exe: 2.40.0
pyinstaller: 6.0.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib: 2023.9

The exported app itself actually works but opens rather slow +-10 seconds.

An image that shows random tk window opening with auto-py-to-exe:
[image: Image that shows random tk window opening with auto-py-to-exe]

An image that shows system dialog stuck outside display border:
[image: Image that shows system dialog stuck outside display border]

I had this issue once before and fixed it but can't find the solution anymore.
Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks

Edit:
The issue also appears when I install auto-py-to-exe in a new clean folder + environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue on macOS as well. The system dialogs on auto-py-to-exe on macOS are broken. Nobody has created an issue report on the official [Auto-Py-To-Exe GitHub](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/issues) yet, it might be worth doing so.

The best way to fix it is either resize the windows, which glitches them back onscreen, or use [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org) and skip out on the GUI instead.

Edit: The blank tk window usually appears anyway, exported apps can take a while to open, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469932/app-created-with-pyinstaller-has-a-slow-startup).

Comment: Hey @fgo thanks for the reply, I also opted to use Pyinstaller with inspiration from the auto-py-to-exe output code. I'll open a ticket once I have time for it.